# searching through a nested list python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have written a code that searches through a web site and returns a nested list of currency values and exchange rates a sample of the output is below

```
[['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']], ['Bahraini Dinar', ['0.37743', '2.64953']]...
```

i need to write a code that takes the input of a name and returns the values associated with it so if i were to type in Argentine Peso it would return

```
[9.44195, 0.10591]
```

but im not really sure how to search through the list

Comment: i think you should be using a dict instead of a nested list, it would make searching for a key way easier

Answer (score 6):

You probably want a dictionary instead of a list:

```
>>> l = [['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']], ['Bahraini Dinar', ['0.37743', '2.64953']]]
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d["Argentine Peso"]
['9.44195', '0.10591']
```

If, for some reason, you must use a list, I use something like the following sometimes:

```
>>> matches = [it for it in l if it[0] == query]
>>> assert len(matches) == 1, "match not found or ambiguous"
>>> matches[0]
```

...though I mostly use it for fuzzy matching. For exact matching, I'd highly recommend dictionaries; that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a one liner:

```
lookup = dict([['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']], ['Bahraini Dinar', ['0.37743', '2.64953']]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant that doesn't use list comprehensions or dicts:

```
currency_list = [['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], 
    ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']], 
    ['Bahraini Dinar', ['0.37743', '2.64953']]]

def search_list(query_string, cur_list):
    for key, val in cur_list:
        if key == query_string:
            return val

search_list('Australian Dollar', currency_list)
```

Each entry in your list is a list of two components:

1. a string indicating a currency (key)
2. a list indicating the currency's value range (value)

In python, you can automatically assign the values of a list of n values to n variables:

```
a, b, c = [7,8,9]
```

That's analogous to how the (key, value) pair is generated at each iteration of the for loop.

However, using a solution which converts the list to a dict will give you the data structure which will perform the fastest lookups.